# Google Storage - only auth users and no delete / rewrite

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I have a social app that users can send images to google cloud storage.

So I need that only auth users can send images AND one user cannot delete another user image or overwrite another user image.

I have this rules:

```
service firebase.storage {
 match /b/{bucket}/o {
   match /images {
     // Cascade read to any image type at any path
     match /{allImages=**} {
       allow read;
     }

     // Allow write files to the path "images/*", subject to the constraints:
     // 1) File is less than 5MB
     // 2) Content type is an image
     // 3) Uploaded content type matches existing content type (if it exists)
     // 4) File name (stored in imageId wildcard variable) is less than 32 characters
     match /{imageId} {
       allow write: if request.resource.size < 5 * 1024 * 1024
                    && request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.*')
                    && (resource == null || request.resource.contentType == resource.contentType)
                    && imageId.size() < 32
     }
   }
 }
}
```

So how can I add that only auth users can send images and they cannot delete / overwrite images after sent?

Thanks!

Comment: Do the users have a google account or not?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I use google auth, but email/password accounts in my website only.

Comment: You can have each user write their uid in the metadata for the file, then use that metadata in security rules to determine if the use should be able to delete their own content.

Comment: @DougStevenson oh, thanks for your answer! I haven't found anything in docs about delete, do you know if it is deny by default? for example, in my actual case, if I don't change anything, every user send images to /images/ can anyuser delete / overwrite images in this folder? or it is deny to all by default? thanks again!

Comment: Everything is denied by default until a rule allows it.

Answer (score 2):

With Google Cloud Storage, you can define ACL on files. But this ACL required a Google account and it's not your case.

So, you have to implement manually the filter and the process for viewing/deleting/writing files. You have several solutions

- You can have a directory per users (/username-at-provider-com -> remove email and url format, you will have issue with them).
- Use only one bucket and directory and add [custom metadata](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata) in your files, with the email value.

In both case, check your user email against the action that they want to perform. And only the service account of your backend that perform these checks is allowed to access to GCS. All the user requests have to be filtered by this backend.